# Does camera.lookAt() still exist in THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was browsing posts about how to set up the camera and many of them mentioned the `lookAt` function. When I go to THREE.js documentation I can't find the method. Where did it go? What should I do in place of the `lookAt` function?

I only found a `lookAt` method for `Object3D`: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt, which does not satisfy the purpose.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camera inherits from Object3D. So it inherits all its methods.

And so it does the PerspectiveCamera and OrthographicCamera as well, inheriting from the base Camera class

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)